# Matching column values with column names and retrieving value

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

| driver_age | vehicle_age | usage | sum_insured | rf_1 | rf_2 | rf_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 17 | business | 3290 | driver_age | vehicle_age | usage |
| 40 | 10 | private | 7000 | vehicle_age | driver_age | usage |

Using this sample dataframe, i need to match values in rf{index} columns with other columns in the dataframe. For instance rf*1 is driverage so in that same row, there will be a new column called "rl_1" and have "25" appended.*

Example output:

| driver_age | vehicle_age | usage | sum_insured | rf_1 | rf_2 | rf_3 | rl_1 | rl_2 | rl_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 17 | business | 3290 | driver_age | vehicle_age | usage | 25 | 17 | business |
| 40 | 10 | private | 7000 | vehicle_age | driver_age | usage | 10 | 40 | private |

This would be the desired output..

I tried many different ways. I tried using a loop to loop through columns with "rf" and if rf matches the column names in df.columns then i tried retrieving the value but did not work.

The caveat is there may not always be 3 rating factors and rating levels. There could be less, there could be more in those cases they have to be nulls..

Comment: Why are the values changed to cell 1, cell 2, etc?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes azure databricks

Comment: @ScootCork sorry about that, edited it , the values are all the same now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the column names that starts with `rf_`. Create a mapping of column name to column value i.e. `name -> value`. Map the values in `rf_` columns to the corresponding column value

```
from itertools import chain

cols = df.select(df.colRegex('`rf_.*`')).columns
m = F.create_map(*chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.drop(*cols).columns]))

df_result = df.select('*', *[m[F.col(c)].alias(f'{c}_new') for c in cols])
```

---

```
df_result.show()
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|driver_age|vehicle_age|   usage|sum_insured|       rf_1|       rf_2| rf_3|rf_1_new|rf_2_new|rf_3_new|
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|        25|         17|business|       3290| driver_age|vehicle_age|usage|      25|      17|business|
|        40|         10| private|       7000|vehicle_age| driver_age|usage|      10|      40| private|
+----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+--------+
```